# I can't get this (simple) loop to work properly

Tags: c, visual-studio, while-loop

I'm in a programming class right now, and was asked to create a program that calculated the sum of a user's input for multiple numbers--then calculate the nth root of the sum. If the number they input was less than 0, the loop is supposed to discard the less than 0 number, then ask again.

Unfortunately, no matter what number I input--it displays "Value needs to be greater than zero!" I tried putting a `fflush(stdin);` statement in the loop, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Here is my code. I really appreciate any and all help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

int mTotalNums, mNth; //amount of numbers in set
float mProd = 1, x, mNroot;

printf("How many numbers are in the set?\n");
scanf("%i", &mTotalNums);

mNth = mTotalNums; //set the value of mTotalNums equal to mNth becuase we'll lose the original value of mTotalNums after the loop

while (mTotalNums > 0) {
    printf("Input number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    if (x > 0) {
        mProd *= x;
    } else
        printf("\nValue needs to be greater than zero!\n");
}

mNroot = pow(mProd, (1 / mNth));

printf("\nThe nth root of the product of %i terms is: %.2f\n", mNth, mNroot);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the 'if' statement to see what the value of 'x' is?

Comment: Either define your x as a float, as you do, and use "%f" in scanf, or define it as a double, and use "%lf". Right now you're using the wrong format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these modifications to your program (added comments with changes made)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    //amount of numbers in set
    int mTotalNums, mNth; 
    // Change to double for added precision
    double mProd = 1.0, x, mNroot;

    printf("How many numbers are in the set?\n");
    scanf("%i", &mTotalNums);

    // Set the value of mTotalNums equal to mNth becuase
    // we'll lose the original value of mTotalNums after the loop
    mNth = mTotalNums; 

    // Don't forget to decrement the loop counter
    while (mTotalNums-- > 0) {
        printf("Input number: ");
        scanf("%lf", &x);
        if (x > 0) {
            mProd *= x;
        } else {
            printf("\nValue needs to be greater than zero!\n");
        }

    }

    // Change to 1.0 to force compiler to treat as a double
    mNroot = pow(mProd, (1.0 / mNth));

    printf("\nThe nth root of the product of %i terms is: %.2f\n", mNth, mNroot);

    return 0;
}
```

You mention "**calculate the nth root of the sum**", but your loop is clearly tallying the cumulative product. To change it to calculate the sum, try the following additions:

```
// Declare a sum variable
double sum =  0;
// Sum inside your while loop
sum += x;
// Calculate the nth root of the sum instead
mNroot = pow(sum, (1.0 / mNth));
```

Comment: I didn't mean to say "nth root of the sum", I meant "nth root of the product". That's my bad. However, I appreciate you going as far as to rewrite my program. That's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`"%lf"` is the scanf format for a `double`, but `x` is declared as `float`.
To scan a float, you have to use the `%f` format.

Note also that `mTotalNums` is not decremented in the loop, so that it will never
terminate.

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Since `x` is declared as a `float`, use `%f` as the scanf format control string. Also, take into account the result of `scanf` (it would be 1 if successfully read one item).

You should enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler, then learn how to use the debugger (notably to run your program step by step, display local variables, etc....).

<sup>(On Linux, if compiling with `gcc -Wall -g` you would get a useful warning, and the `gdb` debugger would be helpful...)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Add printf commands to see what your variables contain before you check them in your logic statements.

You also need to do something to increment/decrement your variable for your while loop... currently nothing is changing mTotalNums, so it will be an infinite loop.

```
  while (mTotalNums > 0) {
      printf("Input number: ");
      scanf("%lf", &x);
      printf("x=%d", x);
      if (x > 0) {
          mProd *= x;
      } else
          printf("\nValue needs to be greater than zero!\n");
      mTotalNums--;
  }
```